# The exponential map exp$: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^* = \mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ is open.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, open-map

This is the first part of Q4 of §1.2 in Dieck's algtop. I'd like to prove this by showing that image of every open subset in the domain is open. But what exactly is the topology with which the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}^*$ is endowed?

Comment: Relevant maybe: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930876/a-covering-map-is-open ?

Comment: @ThePuix Yes, it seems so. So, all I have to do is first prove and then use the fact that the exponential map is a covering map. That's a very nice way of circumventing the specification of the topology on $\mathbb{C}^*$!

Comment: Oh right, sorry that was your actual question. The topology on $\mathbb{C}^*$ is the subspace topology indued by the inlcusion $\mathbb{C}^* \subset \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Oh, of course it's the subspace topology! Thank you!

Comment: $z \to e^z$ is analytic so open (open mapping theorem from complex analysis). In most curricula complex functions are covered way before any algebraic topology courses so Dieck probably assumes you know this already so there is no work to be done.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, I really should have recalled this. Perhaps I ought to refresh my memory on complex analysis before going any further.

Comment: Math assumes perfect recall: you are supposed to know everything that came before. And the *topology* facts from Complex analysis are quite relevent to algebraic topology (historically it is a precursor to many ideas from it, like manifolds, homotopy etc.). Cauchy's formula is probably not that relevant there (though I did need that later in in an operator theory course..) Arzela-Ascoli and compactifications (Riemann sphere) I also encountered first in complex analysis.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I see, thank you.

Comment: A meaningless word like algtop is incapable of ever being a title of a text.